# removeAll Java Issue

Tags: arraylist, removeall

I have an issue where I am creating an arraylist and adding multiple arraylists to this one. 
At some points in the program I need to remove these lists from the one central list. I have been using removeAll(); but this removes all instances of one element. For example the arraylist can contain (1,2,3,4,5) and one can add the list (1,2,3) to it. Yet when you go to remove this list the resultant list now contains (4,5) while it is desired for it to contain (1,2,3,4,5). How can that be accomplished? Thanks for any help.

Comment: Post some code that you have tried...

Comment: Ｉ don't think you can find a good resolution to fix it, because the mechanism of replaceAll.

Comment: Why don't you use the 2 dimension array list:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5022824/how-to-fill-a-two-dimensional-arraylist-in-java-with-integers

Comment: Yeah, that's my suggestion too.

Comment: Please check the answer, I tested that it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you should just use [`remove`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#remove%28java.lang.Object%29) instead of `removeAll`. You can put it in a loop to remove all the elements from a collection:

```java
ArrayList<Integer> bigList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

// Put multiple smaller lists into big list
bigList.addAll(list1);
bigList.addAll(list2);
bigList.addAll(list3);

// Remove list2's elements from bigList
for (Integer i : list2) {
  bigList.remove(i);
}
```

---

**Update:**

Runnable version:

```java
import java.util.*;

public class RemoveTest {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> list1 = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3);
    List<Integer> list2 = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
    List<Integer> list3 = Arrays.asList(9);

    ArrayList<Integer> bigList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    // Put multiple smaller lists into big list
    bigList.addAll(list1);
    bigList.addAll(list2);
    bigList.addAll(list3);

    // Remove list2's elements from bigList
    for (Integer i : list2) {
      bigList.remove(i);
    }

    System.out.println(bigList);
    // Result:
    // [1, 2, 3, 9]
  }
}
```

Comment: @OQJF - Click the link I gave for `remove`. Notice it says it removes a _single instance_ of the given object, whereas `removeAll` removes _all instances_ of _all given objects_. Did you test my code? (I actually haven't yet—I was in the middle of typing a runnable test.)

Comment: Sorry, that's my fault. tested it

Comment: @OQJF - No problem. I had to go double-check the docs about the behavior of `remove` vs `removeAll`, which is why I included the link. I just tested my runnable example and it seems to be working.

Comment: Definitely, remove just remove the first element and removeAll will remove all the element. It will change the elements order but the result is good.

Comment: Yea this may be easier than a 2-d list...I will give it a try. Thanks for the time.